# Bash while loop stripping first part of command until last iteration of a line in file

Tags: bash

I am tying to do something quite simple: Run a command for every line in a file.

So far I have this (and have also tried different permutations of this):

```
URL=$1
COMMENT=${URL##*/}

curl $URL | while read DOMAIN || [[ -n $DOMAIN ]];
    do
        echo $DOMAIN
        echo "pihole -w $DOMAIN --comment $COMMENT -nr"

        pihole -w $DOMAIN --comment $COMMENT -nr
    done
```

The `echos` are there for debugging. What is happening is the following:

It goes line by line through a file hosted on GitHub and for each of those lines it runs: `pihole -w $DOMAIN --comment $COMMENT -nr` - every line is a domain.

However it only runs the full command with the `pihole -w $DOMAIN` portion on the last line, the preceding lines only fire with `--comment $COMMENT -nr`. As you can see from the output here:

```
t.ly
 --comment url_shorteners.txt -nr
 is not a valid argument or domain name!
adf.ly
 --comment url_shorteners.txt -nr
 is not a valid argument or domain name!
www.adf.ly
 --comment url_shorteners.txt -nr
 is not a valid argument or domain name!
bit.ly
 --comment url_shorteners.txt -nr
 is not a valid argument or domain name!
www.bit.ly
 --comment url_shorteners.txt -nr
 is not a valid argument or domain name!
goo.gl
 --comment url_shorteners.txt -nr
 is not a valid argument or domain name!
ow.ly
 --comment url_shorteners.txt -nr
 is not a valid argument or domain name!
www.ow.ly
 --comment url_shorteners.txt -nr
 is not a valid argument or domain name!
amzn.to
 --comment url_shorteners.txt -nr
 is not a valid argument or domain name!
amzn.com
pihole -w amzn.com --comment url_shorteners.txt -nr
  [i] amzn.com already exists in whitelist, no need to add!
```

As you can see from the echo that prints the command about to be run, for some reason the first part is stripped.

Am I missing something in terms of escaping or piping?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like the domain list you're downloading has DOS/Windows-style line endings, which can cause all sorts of confusion (see ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)). Try putting `set -x` at the beginning to get an execution trace, and you'll see a `\r` at the end of the `$DOMAIN` value. In this case, I'd use `... while IFS=$'\r' read ...` to trim it. BTW, use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to spot other potential problems in your script.

Comment: @GordonDavisson this was highly informative and thank you for the link as well, have saved that. Could you please add this as a main answer so that I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future answer seekers.

Gordon Davisson had the answer, I was editing the file between my windows machine and my Linux machine. Windows appended `\r` to the end of lines in the file.

Adding the following to my loop fixed the issue:

```
while IFS=$'\r' read
```

A handy website and tip that Gordon Davisson provided was the following site: [Shell Check](https://www.shellcheck.net/).